# CS:GO sound effects and voices work, music doesn't play

Tags: sound, games

I'm having no music in Counter Strike: Global Offensive (Steam), even though gun fire, menu sound effects and voices play fine.
Here's what I noticed: it won't play .mp3 files, which is exactly the format of those music files. Here is the output from the developer console:

```
[Sound] S_StartSound(): Failed to load sound 'music/valve_csgo_01/mainmenu.mp3'. Can't create mixer.
```

It keeps printing the same line forever. While playing a map, it prints different file names, as expected.

Ubuntu's restricted extras are installed, and .mp3 files DO play in Rhythmbox.
I just came from Ubuntu MATE to the original Ubuntu, and it was the same there. However, it worked in Fedora and Arch.

This Ubuntu install is pretty clean and is mostly configured with default settings.

Comment: This is a recently introduced bug by the looks.  You can track the resolution here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/csgo-osx-linux/issues/1392

Comment: Yes, thanks for the link. I feel better for it not being something on my side.